# How to add Isotope jQuery in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, jquery, requirejs-config.js

I have added and configured the Isotope jQuery in Magento 2.3.3. But, its working and showing error as below:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).isotope is not a function**

I have tried all the solutions but none of them are worked.

Have anyone an idea how to configure Isotope js in Magento2?

[image: requirejs-config.js]

[image]

[image]

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> try this

Answer (score 0):

in your `requirejs-config.js` try this one:

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            'isotope': 'Magento_Theme/js/isotope.pkgd'
        }
    },

    shim: {
        'isotope': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Your other js code looks fine. After that you need to check if your `isotope.pkgd.js` is loading in DOM. if it is going in `404` then you need to check path of `isotope.pkgd.js`

Comment: I tried with the above code and still got the same error. Also, I have checked the path of the jquery and it's fine.

Comment: I am using https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.js

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this way

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            'isotope': 'Magento_Theme/js/isotope.pkgd'
        }
    },

    shim: {
        'isotope': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

You miss the Talk break in your js file

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your template

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'isotope' ],
        function( require, $, Isotope ) {
            // require jquery-bridget, it's included in isotope.pkgd.js
            require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget' ],
                function( jQueryBridget ) {
                    // make Isotope a jQuery plugin
                    jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
                    // now you can use $().isotope()
                    $('.grid').isotope({
                        // ..your code
                    });
                    
                }
            );
        });
</script>
```